# What have to be done to deliver on Docker and avoid to accumulate images?

Tags: docker, release

I use Docker to execute a website I make.
When a release have to be delivered, I have to build a new Docker image and start a new Container from it.

The problem is that images et containers are accumulating and taking huge space.
Besides the delivery, I need to stop the running container and delete it and the source image too.

I don't need Docker command lines but a checklist or a process to not forget anything.

For instance:
-Stop running container
-Delete stopped container
-Delete old image
-Build new image
-Start new container

Am I missing something?
I'm not used to Docker, maybe there are best practices to this pretty classical use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The local workflow that works for me is:

1. Do core development locally, *without Docker*.  Things like interactive debuggers and live reloading work just fine in a non-Docker environment without weird hacks or root access, and installing the tools I need usually involves a single `brew` or `apt-get` step.  Make all of my pytest/junit/rspec/jest/... tests pass.
2. `docker build` a new image.
3. `docker stop && docker rm` the old container.
4. `docker run` a new container.
5. When the number of old images starts to bother me, `docker system prune`.

If you're using Docker Compose, you might be able to replace the middle set of steps with `docker-compose up --build`.

In a production environment, the sequence is slightly different:

1. When your CI system sees a new commit, after running the repository's local tests, it `docker build && docker push` a new image.  The image has a unique tag, which could be a timestamp or source control commit ID or version tag.
2. Your deployment system (could be the CI system or a separate CD system) tells whatever cluster manager you're using (Kubernetes, a Compose file with Docker Swarm, Nomad, an Ansible playbook, ...) about the new version tag.  The deployment system takes care of stopping, starting, and removing containers.
3. If your cluster manager doesn't handle this already, run a cron job to `docker system prune`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
docker system df
```

to investigate the space used by docker.

After that you can use

```
docker system prune -a --volumes
```

to remove unused components. Containers you should stop them yourself before doing this, but this way you are sure to cover everything.